# Convert SQL query to Cloud Firestore on Android development

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do i convert SELECT USERID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME = "JOHN" to Cloud Firestore on android?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference customerRef = rootRef.collection("Customer");
Query query = customerRef.whereEqualTo("name", "John");
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the ID? like the 7E6ID...?

Comment: If you are using a `get()` call, yes and then you should use: `document.getId()`.

Comment: Good to hear that. Cheers!